# Create a Cellular Automata rule in Mathematica

Tags: cellular-automata

I want to create an image in a cellular automata, more specifically an image of an object, like a turtle for example. I found this article online, and i am trying to replicate the results for growing an animal from a single alive cell in Mathemathica.

https://distill.pub/2020/growing-ca/

To generate such an image i have to make a very specific set of rules to give me the desired outcome.
The CA will have k colours and the rules will be depending on the colours of the neighbours and the "order".
An example of a rule that im trying to do is...
if the cell in question is green and the neighbours are as such:

(green, green, darker green)
(green, green, darker green)
(green, green, green)

The result of the cell should be darker green.

How can i create a cellular automata with this type of rules?

I've tried many ways to specify such rules, but none worked.
And to be honest, I don't think this is the more efficient way to replicate the results on the article, but i don't have any more ideias.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That page crashed my browser.